# How can I get Shoreditch theming in Backdrop?

Tags: backdrop, shoreditch

I've noticed some of the styling doesn't come through on Backdrop when Shoreditch is installed. For example, when viewing a contact, the tabs do not stack on the left, as they do on Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

I found that Backdrop does not add as many classes to the `<body>` by default, and adding this to the CiviCRM administrative theme's `template.php` goes a long way towards getting things styled as expected:

```
/**
 * Implements theme_preprocess_page().
 *
 */
function MYADMINTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $path = current_path();
  $path_parts = explode('/', $path);
  $segment = 'page-';
  foreach ($path_parts as $path_part) {
    $segment .= $path_part;
    $variables['classes'][] = $segment;
    $segment .= '-';
  }
}
```

Follow here:

- https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch/issues/539